# Youtube Video dispalying in shockwave player instead of youtube video

Tags: wordpress, youtube, shockwave

the videos being displayed/embedded are now displaying in shock wave players, this never happened before

my client said they just posted a new update and all the you tube videos went to shock wave players and are now being played in a large screen rather than directly on the website (like the hulu video)

code wasn't touched at all (WordPress site)

link:
http://www.mattemig.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the errors in the console...

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  /v2/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/lightview-plus/js/spinners/spinners.js/?ver=3.1.0:1 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  /v2/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/lightview-plus/js/lightview/lightview.js/?ver=3.1.0:1
```

...it looks like these two scripts being referenced in the code are missing or have incorrect paths:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.mattemig.net/v2/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/lightview-plus/js/spinners/spinners.js?ver=3.1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.mattemig.net/v2/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/lightview-plus/js/lightview/lightview.js?ver=3.1.0'></script>
```

The source code says the youtube video is supposed to be played inside a Lightview. If the js can't put it in one, that would make sense why it's being embedded full screen.